# window.location.href does not work for the seconf time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
file_1.js
demo : function(){
  var idList = [];
  idList.push(1);
  window.location.href = "#/transferToReport/" + idList;
  return false;
}

file_2.js
window.Router = Backbone.Router
.extend({

  routes : {
  "transferToReport/:fileIdList" : "transferToReport",
  },

  transferToReport : function(fileIdList) {
     console.log("print")
  }
});



templateLoader.load([
    ..//load some templates
 ], function() {
  location.hash = '';
  app = new Router();
  Backbone.history.start();
 });
```

I want to call a function transferToReport() in file_2.js from demo() function in file_1.js
The above code executes for the first time , but after that is does not execute.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: hi, can you explain what does not work ? like, is it that the page does not scroll up to that div ?

Comment: hi tks, there are some issues around syntax in file_2. for e.g. `transferToReport`: `function()`. Could you check and post back (just to e sure).

Comment: @tyskr corrected the code now

Comment: sorry. one more thing: `app = new Router(); Backbone.history.start();` needs to be declared outside the extend too.

Comment: I think once you use Backbone router the ideal way to navigate would using : https://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate. There are some options there (`trigger, replace`) too.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem like an obvious answer, so sorry if you have already thought of this, but are you including the redirect function on the page you are redirecting to?